# torsion sheaf/ quasi-coherent sheaf on projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume $S$ is a graded ring generated by finite elements of $S_1$ as $S_0$ algebra. I came across a claim that $\tilde{M}$ is not determined by $M$, with a counterexample $M =\underset{n\geq 0}{\sum} M_n $ and $N=\underset{n\geq n_0}{\sum} M_n$, the goal is to prove that $M_{(f)} = N_{(f)}$ for any $f$ homogeneous in $S_+$. For $f$ of degree 1, it is easy. But for general $f$ is it still true? I can't construct the isomorphism.

For degree 1, it is just $\psi:M_{(f)}\rightarrow N_{(f)}$ sending $\frac{m}{f^k}$ to $\frac{m}{f^{k-n_0}}$ with the obvious converse by multiplying $f^{n_0}$. Many thanks!

---

It turns out that the confusion comes from the fact that the grading on $N$ is the old grading, and we view the lower degree part as $0.$

Comment: $\dfrac{m}{f^k}=\dfrac{mf^{n_0}}{f^{k+n_0}}?$

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for the confirmation! I'm just a beginner in algebraic geometry and hence don't feel confident enough to write an answer (my mere calculations probably won't help the OP). Can you please post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Shivering Soldier](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/588038/shivering-soldier) in the comments, the key fact here is $$\frac{m}{f^n}=\frac{f^km}{f^{k+n}}.$$
Consider the obvious injection $N\to M$. Since localization is exact, $N_f\to M_f$ is also an injection, and as $N\to M$ preserves the grading, we have that the image of $N_{(f)}\subset N_f$ lands in $M_{(f)}$, so we have an injective map $N_{(f)}\to M_{(f)}$. To see that it's surjective, let $\frac{m}{f^n}\in M_{(f)}$: then $\frac{m}{f^n}=\frac{f^km}{f^{k+n}}$ for any $k$, and so fixing $k>n_0$, we see that $f^km\in M_{(n+k)\deg f} = N_{(n+k)\deg f}$ and so $\frac{m}{f^n}$ is in the image of $N_{(f)}\to M_{(f)}$. So this map is surjective and therefore an isomorphism.

Note that no assumptions on $f$ besides being homogeneous of positive degree are necessary.

Comment: I think the map $N \rightarrow M$ doesn't preserve the grading: in particular, it sends a degree $0$ element of $N$, which is in $M_{n_0}$ to degree $n_0.$ So $N_{(f)}$ doesn't land in $M_{(f)}$

Comment: @Ivan What are you talking about? The map $N\to M$ is $\bigoplus_{n\geq n_0} M_n\to \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} M_n$ defined by the **identity** on $M_n$ for $n\geq n_0$.

Comment: The degree zero part of $⨁_{n≥n_0}M_n$ is $M_{n_0}$, which is degree $n_0$ in your target.

Comment: No, the degree zero part of that is $0$. The module $N$ is defined to have $0$ in degree $<n_0$ and $M_n$ in degree $n$ when $n\geq n_0$.

Comment: Many thanks! it's great! This is where the confusion comes. I was thinking $⨁_{n≥n_0}M_n$ as $M({n_0})$ the twisted module. Do you think that ${M} \tilde{ } \cong {M(n)}\tilde{ }$ is true as well?

Comment: That's completely false.

Comment: Absolutely not. That's also a completely different question than this one and would be better suited to a new post.

Comment: What you've written is not even an argument - it's just two false claims with no justification. It's also not really on topic as a comment on this post, and I have no wish to discuss it further with you. Good day.

Comment: Thank you! I realized the problem.